# Nabla Special Character Shows as Null Character

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I have a page that uses the nabla character for bullets on a menu. The code for it is &nabla;. However, on my machine as well as some others around the office, this character comes up as the null character, [], in IE. In Firefox, though, it displays the actual character. My question is whether there is a fix for this so I can make sure anyone viewing this site will see the actual character. Is there a browser font that needs to be installed on any machine that views this site, or is it an issue that can be fixed from my end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty square character is not the null character, it is a visual placeholder - a representation of a Unicode character for which there is no associated glyph in the current font.

There are couple of possible issues:

- your page does not have explicit encoding associated with it and your IE is configured to use Win-1252 as default instead of Unicode.
- the font family you specify in the CSS is missing on your computer and IE fallback font is different from Firefox and does not have tha babka char.

Make sure your page explicitly specifies Unicode encoding and use the iE developer tools and Firebug to examine the actual rendered style for the bullet and see what font is being used by the two browsers.

Comment: +1.  It's a good idea to explicitly state the content encoding of your page, and UTF-8 is often the best choice. If you're worried that users won't have an available font with the nabla character defined, you can also style your list to use a small image as the bullet.

Comment: The font family is on this machine, so I don't think thats the problem. However, your first suggestion sounds like that could be it. How would I specify Unicode encoding explicitly? (Sorry if there's an obvious answer to that, but I'm an inexperienced student developing web sites for a reasearch group. I'm not the most intelligent in this field.)

Comment: To explicitly specify Unicode encoding, add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` to your page `<head>` section.

Comment: Gave it a try, but it didn't seem to work. So I'm guessing it's an issue with the individual machines?

Comment: Did you clean the browser cache before trying to reload the page?

Comment: Yes. Browser cache was cleared, but they're still displaying as [].